# Referencing Folder-level scope credentials in declarative Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

## Question

I have the following script as part of a declarative pipeline in Jenkins

```
stages {
    stage('sql') { 
        steps {
            step([
                $class: 'SQLPlusRunnerBuilder',
                credentialsId:"sis-database-prod-schema-test",
                instance:"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=db_${ENVIRONMENT}.int.excelsior.edu)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=${ENVIRONMENT})))",
                scriptType:'userDefined', 
                script: '',
                scriptContent:"select*from dual",
                customOracleHome: '/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64'
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice I am referencing the credential ID `sis-database-prod-schema-test`.  When I scope this credential globally this script works.  However, when I scope the credential at the folder level it get the following error

> ERROR: Invalid credentials [sis-database-prod-schema-test]. Failed to initialize credentials or load user and password

Here is a screenshot of my folder-level scope configuration

[image: folder-level scope]

## Additional Information

When I scope the credential at the folder level I can see it in a configuration drop down element **ONLY** when I am in the appropriate folder.  So, in my mind, the scope configuration is correct but there referencing ( in the code ) is wrong.

[image]

> The entry I have highlighted is the sis-database-prod-schema-test credential ID.  The one below it ( sis-test-database-prod-schema ) is a global credential unrelated to this question

## Edit : This Was a Known Issue

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/jenkinsci/sqlplus-script-runner-plugin/issues/41) that the author was unable to fix. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/sqlplus-script-runner-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/sqlplus/script/runner/SQLPlusRunnerBuilder.java#L172).  You can issue a pull request to fix the bug.

Comment: Looks like it's a [known bug](https://github.com/jenkinsci/sqlplus-script-runner-plugin/issues/41) that the author was unable to fix.  Maybe you can submit a PR?  Seems like relevant code is [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/sqlplus-script-runner-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/sqlplus/script/runner/SQLPlusRunnerBuilder.java#L172)?

Comment: @kthompso good catch.  Can you write this as an answer and I will accept it?  I cant delete the question after comments are place on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you still care but I just submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/sqlplus-script-runner-plugin/pull/65) for this that got accepted. Now this problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Known Issue

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/jenkinsci/sqlplus-script-runner-plugin/issues/41) that the author was unable to fix. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/sqlplus-script-runner-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/sqlplus/script/runner/SQLPlusRunnerBuilder.java#L172).  You can issue a pull request to fix the bug.